# Creating polygon features composed of scalable points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, point, symbology, forest-ecology

I want to represent a forest using symbols I create (stylised trees).
I considered two options:
- A point feature.
- A polygon feature.
This is the one I'd use, as a forest is better represented with an area rather than with a cluster of points. Among the ESRI style symbols there are some which are close to what I'm looking for (e.g. "Scattered Trees 1" symbology).
I want to create a similar symbology using a picture I created, like a small tree (and have it multiplied homogeneously across the polygon area).
I know that it is impossible to scale such symbols (the small trees composing the polygon filling) when zooming in and out. But Point features can be scaled. Is there a way to distribute point features in order to cover a specific area (as if I were drawing a polygon)?

Comment: Please ask only one question per Question.

Comment: I edited to have only one question asked.

Comment: Thank you.  Have you considered using *both* a polygon (dark green line with faint light green fill) *and* a scalable pointmarker?  The points can be regular/systematic grid of points, with clusters dissolved by the polygon in which they were Intersected.

Comment: It seems to accomplish what I was looking for. I just need to create my own pointmarker. The only flaw of this approach is that the pointmarkes result often cut at the edges of the polygon but I might be asking too much ;)